# Changing an image in HTML by clicking an option

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have read the articles on this site for HTML5 canvas based product builder. I'm very much impressed with the website: http://printio.ru/tees/new. I need a similar site with similar options for customize the product. I see the developer of this site (http://printio.ru/tees/new) suggested http://fabricjs.com/demos/ for customize the product. However, this is not sufficient because the "FabricJS" do not teach us how the color of the shirt will change as you can see on the demo site (http://printio.ru/tees/new). I need the code how can I change the shirt's color by clicking on various color options available similar to the site http://printio.ru/tees/new. Please post your answers.

Comment: This more likely a feature request to an ecommerce product and the question is not suited to StackOverflow.com as described in FAQ.

Comment: I suggest you try to learn how to code such thing from image carousel or any other public example.

Comment: Adobe Photoshop or any other better-than-basic image editor will let you change the hue of your t-shirt.

Comment: I think both of you did not understand what I want to say. May be I am failed to explain my thoughts. However, if you can see the website http://printio.ru/tees/new, you can understand the whole idea. It is about HTML5 - Canvas based custom product builder. Still need your help.

Comment: I suspect we both understand...although I, for one, don't understand the Russian on the website ;)   I stand behind my comment.  If you spend 30 minutes in Photoshop you can produce very nice looking images in all your various color options.  Alternatively, you can spend a **couple of days** learning enough html canvas to do the job.  It's your choice.  If you choose to learn html canvas, then spend some time coding and come back here with more specific programming questions...lots of people here will help with your specific questions!

Comment: Sorry. It is my fault. My intention is to build online products, not through PhotoShop. Clicking on the First option from the right hand side of the shirt, you may select any color. Imediate effect, the shirt image will be changed. Also, there is so many options in the right hand side of the shirt image. Please suggest.